# Getting LatLng parameter null after Migrating the new Place SDK Client

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Recently I have migrated the new place SDK client in my application but getting latLng parameter null, Using following dependency

```
'implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

Implemented the following code

```
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME);
            FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeFields).build();
            // Call findCurrentPlace and handle the response (first check that the user has granted permission).
            placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(((response) -> {
                FindCurrentPlaceResponse mFindCurrentPlaceResponse = response;
                Log.i("MainActivity", mFindCurrentPlaceResponse.toString());
                sourceTxt.setText(response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getAddress());
                RIDE_REQUEST.put("s_address", response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getAddress());
                RIDE_REQUEST.put("s_latitude", response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getLatLng() != null ? response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getLatLng().latitude : 0.0);
                RIDE_REQUEST.put("s_longitude", response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getLatLng() != null ? response.getPlaceLikelihoods().get(0).getPlace().getLatLng().longitude : 0.0);
            })).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                }
            });
```

Getting the following in response

> FindCurrentPlaceResponse{placeLikelihoods=[PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Shri Vallabh Galaxy, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.1573291110992432}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Simran Manor, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.1220559597015381}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Adinath Heights, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.1210990524291992}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Shanti Heights Apartment, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.1030252552032471}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Vrind Residency, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.09741650581359863}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Radha Rukmani Garden, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.06733533382415771}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Shanti Heights Block-B, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.05104345798492432}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Navin Pri Matric Anusuchit Jati Kanya Chatrawas, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.04583617210388184}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Shanti Heights, Block - D, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.02887811899185181}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Shiv Temple, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.02057793617248535}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=NRB Indore, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.01496525406837463}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=Swapnil Palace, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null, websiteUri=null}, likelihood=0.01366739869117737}, PlaceLikelihood{place=Place{address=null, attributions=null, id=null, latLng=null, name=RBD Block C, openingHours=null, phoneNumber=null, photoMetadatas=null, plusCode=null, priceLevel=null, rating=null, types=null, userRatingsTotal=null, viewport=null

Unable to figure out why every thing is coming null except only name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer Actually I was missing to pass the required parameters, 
While creating the placeFields object i was only passing Place.Field.Name

```
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME);
```

but to make the things working I need to paas all the required parameters which I need to get from response like this

```
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG,Place.Field.ADDRESS);
```